# Livewire Pagination does work after Filter and Search and vice versa

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I was working on a project that is using livewire version 3 and I was working with the Staff Table. Now, the table has Filter and Search which is both working and it also has Pagination which also work. The error only occurs when:

1. Using the filter or search and then using the pagination.
2. Using the pagination and then using either filter or search.

After searching, I fix the issue with number 2 by resetting the pagination but the number 1 still there. I thought this might be a problem with `wire:navigate` and so I removed it but still did not fix the problem.

This is the error I recieved:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException

The GET method is not supported for route livewire/update. Supported methods: POST.
```

This is my livewire component:

```
namespace App\Livewire\Portal;

use App\Models\Staff;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Livewire\Attributes\Url;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class StaffDataTable extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    #[Url(keep: true)]
    public string $search = '';

    #[Url(keep: true)]
    public int $perPage = 10;

    #[Url(keep: true)]
    public string $sortBy = 'name';

    #[Url(keep: true)]
    public string $sortDirection = 'ASC';

    public function updatingSearch(): void
    {
        $this->resetPage();
    }

    public function render(): View
    {
        return view('livewire.portal.staff-data-table', [
            'staffs' => Staff::whereLike('name', $this->search)
                ->orWhereLike('email', $this->search)
                ->when($this->sortBy, function ($query) {
                    return $query->orderBy($this->sortBy, $this->sortDirection);
                })
                ->paginate($this->perPage ?? 10),
        ]);
    }
}
```

And this is my blade file:

```
@php
    use App\Models\Staff;
@endphp

<div class="bg-white sm:rounded border border-gray-200">
    <div class="p-4 flex items-center justify-between">
        <div wire:ignore class="w-full max-w-2xl relative">
            <i data-feather="search" class="w-4 h-4 stroke-gray-400 absolute top-1/2 left-4 -translate-y-1/2"></i>
            <x-form.input
                type="text"
                wire:model.live="search"
                placeholder="Search staff..."
                class="pl-10"
            />
        </div>

        <x-button variety="secondary">
            <i data-feather="file" class="w-4 h-4"></i>
            Export
        </x-button>
    </div>

    <div class="p-4 border-t border-gray-200">
        <div class="inline-flex items-center gap-4">
            <div class="inline-flex items-center gap-2">
                <x-form.label for="perPage" class="whitespace-nowrap">Per Page</x-form.label>
                <x-form.select class="w-20" wire:model.live="perPage" id="perPage">
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="30">30</option>
                    <option value="50">50</option>
                </x-form.select>
            </div>

            <div class="inline-flex items-center gap-2">
                <x-form.label for="sortBy" class="whitespace-nowrap">Sort By</x-form.label>
                <x-form.select wire:model.live="sortBy" id="sortBy">
                    <option value="name">Name</option>
                    <option value="email">Email</option>
                    <option value="role">Role</option>
                    <option value="status">Status</option>
                </x-form.select>
            </div>

            <div class="inline-flex items-center gap-2">
                <x-form.label for="sortDirection" class="whitespace-nowrap">Sort Direction</x-form.label>
                <x-form.select wire:model.live="sortDirection" id="sortDirection">
                    <option value="ASC">Ascending</option>
                    <option value="DESC">Descending</option>
                </x-form.select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <x-table>
        <x-slot:thead>
            <x-table.header>Name</x-table.header>
            <x-table.header class="hidden sm:table-cell">Email</x-table.header>
            <x-table.header class="hidden sm:table-cell">Role</x-table.header>
            <x-table.header class="hidden sm:table-cell">Status</x-table.header>
            @can('create', Staff::class)
                <x-table.header class="text-right">Actions</x-table.header>
            @endcan
        </x-slot:thead>

        <x-slot:tbody>
            @foreach($staffs as $staff)
                <x-table.row>
                    <x-table.cell class="font-medium">{{ $staff->name }} {{ auth('portal')->id() === $staff->id ? '(You)': '' }}</x-table.cell>
                    <x-table.cell class="text-gray-500 hidden sm:table-cell">{{ $staff->email }}</x-table.cell>
                    <x-table.cell class="text-gray-500 hidden sm:table-cell">{{ $staff->role }}</x-table.cell>
                    <x-table.cell class="text-gray-500 hidden sm:table-cell">
                        <x-badge :variety="$staff->getStatusColor()">
                            {{ $staff->status }}
                        </x-badge>
                    </x-table.cell>
                    @can('create', Staff::class)
                        @if (auth()->user()->email !== $staff->email)
                            <x-table.cell class="text-right">
                                <x-button.link
                                    variety="secondary"
                                    href="{{ route('portal.staff.edit', $staff) }}"
                                    wire:navigate
                                >
                                    Edit
                                </x-button.link>
                            </x-table.cell>
                        @endif
                    @endcan
                </x-table.row>
            @endforeach
        </x-slot:tbody>
    </x-table>

    <x-table.pagination :collection="$staffs"/>
</div>
```

It's not a full page component and it's the only livewire component in the page either. Can someone explain what's happening with it? Thank you in advanced.